# Ignorar campos a validar usando jquery.validate.1.8.1

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery.validate

Tenho um projeto na empresa onde estou a estagiar e tenho tido uns erros na hora de validar uns inputs. Uso ASP.NET MVC, Razor, e Javascript. Na hora de submeter todos os campos recebo um erro. Ao usar o consolo do Chrome descobri que este campo:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Material.DateCreated)
```

Não é válido. Quando fui ver o valor, estava correto por isso acho que não preciso de validar pois o valor vem sempre do controller. O que eu queria fazer é usar algo deste estilo:

```
$("#myform").validate({
ignore: "#target"
});
```

Parecia que tinha a solução, mas no meu código o que tenho é ´$form.valid()´ e não sei como implementar esse 'ignore' como no código acima pois dá erro. Pelo que pesquisei acho que a versão que está no projeto está desatualizada, pois não consigo encontrar nada no google com **valid()**, só me aparece **validate()**.

Answer (score 0):

A solução que encontrei para o meu problema foi a seguinte:

Tirei o

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Material.DateCreated)
```

e na ação POST no **controller** coloco a data atual assim:

```
Material.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
```

A diferença agora é que não coloco a data na ação GET e dei a volta.